# Offset a Vlookup across multiple sheets

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

I recently received help on creating a formula to fill in data on a Google sheet for customer orders, this goes between sheet1 (master) and sheet2 (selected data only, depending on the reference cell).

The reference cell is a drop down, I then entered the range from sheet1.

The areas collecting data have this formula;
=iferror( vlookup($H$14, ORDERS!$A$2:$Z, column(ORDERS!$E:$E), false) ) and I change the column() accordingly - this works perfectly.

However, I have one area that requires an offset to cater for multiple products in the same column but the next row. How would I change the above formula to get this to offset to the cell below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `offset()`, like this:

`=iferror( offset( vlookup($H$14, ORDERS!$A$2:$Z, column(ORDERS!$E:$E), false), 1, 0 ) )`